# Semantics as syntactic proof morphisms

Tags: logic

A [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) of a theory $T$ is usually defined as a set $M$ and functions representing the symbols in the signature of $T$. However, the soundness property of models makes me think we can also give a completely syntactic definition of a model of $T$ :

- a morphism of formulas, from the formulas of the language of $T$ to the formulas of the language of the ZFC set theory. Usually it replaces $\forall x$ by $\forall x\in M$, likewise for $\exists$ and it preserves all propositional connectives.
- a morphism of proofs, that transforms a proof $T\vdash F$ into a proof $ZFC \vdash F'$, where $F'$ is the interpretation of the formula $F$ by the previous morphism.

Then we get the usual property that, if ZFC is consistent and if $F'$ is true in the model $M$ (ie if $ZFC\vdash F'$), then $T$ cannot refute $F$.

Am I missing some kinds of models here ? Or then do we simply say semantics because ZFC "makes more sense" than an arbitrary theory $T$ ? Note that there are also categorical semantics, is some other categories than Sets.

Comment: What precisely are morphisms of formulas or proofs?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Well... that's part of the question. For the usual models, the morphism of formulas is the usual interpretation of formulas in the model. The morphism of proofs is obtained by pasting the proofs of the interpreted axioms. There might be other ways to compile proofs into proofs, giving more general notions of models. At least they have to commute with the negation, so that a refutation in $T$ would morph into a refutation in the model.